# Help Understanding Error Report

Tags: erlang

Can anyone explain why I get the following error when I run: `erl -noshell -s simple_server` and then `telnet 127.0.0.1 1084`? The code itself is below the error message.

> =ERROR REPORT==== 13-Aug-2011::23:12:05 === Error in process <0.30.0>
>   with exit value:
>   {{badmatch,{error,closed}},[{simple_server,wait_accept,1}]}

```
  -module(simple_server).
  -compile(export_all).

  start() ->
      {ok, ListenSoc} = gen_tcp:listen(1084, [binary, {active, false}]),
      wait_accept(ListenSoc).

   wait_accept(ListenSoc) ->
      {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSoc),
      spawn(?MODULE, wait_accept, [ListenSoc]),
      send_resp(Socket).

  send_resp(Socket) ->
      gen_tcp:send(Socket, "Response from simple server...\n"),
      ok = gen_tcp:close(Socket).
```

Answer (score 4):

This thing:

```
{{badmatch,{error,closed}},
 [{simple_server,wait_accept,1}]}
```

should be read as: "We are in simple_server:wait_accept/1" and we got a badmatch error (see http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html#id81191). This means that our match expression

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(ListenSock),
```

returned `{error, closed}` (as it is the only match expression in that function it is simple). Why it returned that is a bit murky to me. The best bet is that the process calling the `start/0` function has terminated and then the listen socket has been closed because of that termination (this happens automatically). Note that an error in the erlang shell will restart it and as such close the listen socket.

Answer (score 3):

When a socket is created it's linked to the current process, which known as socket controlling process. When controlling process is terminated all linked sockets are just closed. In your case `ListenSoc` is closed when `send_resp()` is over (so controlling process of the socket is terminated) and `gen_tcp:accept(ListenSoc)` in newly created process returns `{error, closed}`.

Easiest fix is to add call to [gen_tcp:contorolling_process/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#controlling_process-2) in `wait_accept` like this:

```
...
Pid = spawn(?MODULE, wait_accept, [ListenSoc]),
ok = gen_tcp:controlling_process(ListenSoc, Pid),
...
```

But in real projects it's better to loop in listen socket controlling process. You can get an idea from `Nicolas Buduroi` answer.

Comment: And to be really proper, you should spawn the process _without_ the socket, call `controlling_process/2` and _then_ send the socket to the process in a message. This is to avoid the process still being able to read from a socket it doesn't yet own!